# Which `main` is used if I specify more than one

Tags: c++

Along with a couple of others, the following are valid prototypes for `main()`:

1. `int main(void)`
2. `int main(int, char**)`

In C we can't overload functions so it's never possible to have both. But in C++ that's not true. If I were to have both in a compiled C++ executable, then which one is used? Does it depend on the command line? What does the standard say?

Comment: You're really not supposed to have more than one `main` function. There should be a warning or error generated if you try.

Comment: You cannot overload the main entry point of an application, that just makes no sense...

Comment: Your compiler will probably not compile the code.

Comment: "If I were to have both in a compiled C++ executable" then you would have a broken compiler. Why don't you try it out?

Comment: My compiler complained horribly, but it's quite old.

Comment: Note you can use [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) to try things on up to date compilers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C++11 §3.6.1/2:

> **”** This function shall not be overloaded.